# Do I have to decrypt my hard drive when switching OS?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, truecrypt

I have encrypted my whole laptop using TrueCrypt on Windows 7 and I would like to switch to Ubuntu. Do I have to select *Permanently decrypt system partition or drive* before installing Ubuntu or can I just install it with no problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had issues when I didn't decrypt the files, and I basically had to delete them because they were just useless. So, you should `Permanently decrypt system partition or drive` before installing Ubuntu.